# Accessing SvelteKit vite local development server from Android phone

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have built a landing page with Sveltekit, and I want to test the website on my Android phone while developing the mobile view, is there any way to do this?

Before using Svelte (when I used plain HTML, CSS and js) I would just run the live server from vs code and search for the computer ip followed by the port number, but that does not seem to work for Sveltekit projects.

Comment: Are you passing the `--host` (in package.json) for when running `npm run dev`? In the terminal you should get the local IPs  like: `192.168.*.*:5173` you can access from your device on the local network (Also you can access via *Developer* mode on your Android. connect via USB, etc... and access the developer tools on the PC's browser for debugging...) there's lots of articles online on that general topic - should apply for SvelteKit as well.